# How can i retrieve token?

Tags: usdt

I have two wallets. Trust wallet and NDAX wallet. From trust wallet I have send USDT token on Ploygon network to my NDAX wallet as Matic polygon but I didnt know it doesnt support polygon network.however In this case from my trust wallet is showing me the transfer is a success where as no reflection on NDAX wallet.

In this case how can i reverse the transaction anget back the tokens in trust wallet?
thank you

Comment: Did you use a bridge? NDAX seems to be an exchange, so you will have to ask their customer support if they can recover it.

Answer (score 1):

Can't reverse it, and since you don't have the key you can't transfer it out. You need to ask them if they have a recovery service.